# "the article is" or "the article looks": which one is correct and formal?

Tags: email

I was writing a Thank You email and I am confused with my grammar of the sentences

> Thanks. The article is perfect now

or,

> Thanks. The article looks perfect now

or,

> Thanks. The articles is great now

Which one is formal and correct ?

Comment: If you are looking for a formal display of gratitude, "thanks" is a no-go.

Comment: Looks can be deceptive. Say what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The article is perfect now.**

appears the best to me. Because -

1. The article **looks** perfect - *almost makes reader feel as if the replier is judging by looks. Only a supreme determiner independent of all obligations would haughtily glance at something and arrive at a decision immediately. Judging by looks, even in the phrase, exerts unnecessary authority from a psychological viewpoint.*
2. The article is **great** - *is not a very formal thing to say. "Great" isn't a very descriptive adjective. It's approximates the condition of something or someone with embedded warmth and casualness, while also enthusing the listener.*

Overall, "is perfect" carries the right amounts of politeness, authority and precision to me. An alternative way to phrase yourself if you still desire to keep some form of **looking at the article** present in your speech would be to say -

> *The article **appears perfect** now.*